# Delete field using curl in couchdb

Tags: document, couchdb, field

I searched and didn't found, can I delete a field of a couchdb's document using curl ?

The most I can do is delete a document:

```
 curl -X DELETE http://localhost:5984/users/jack?rev=1-cee2abbbe4afefa9b3b5db10260c0c94
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want delete any field, you need edit document via PUT method, where you send all fields of document, id and rev. included, but without field for delete.
Http method DELETE is only for delete complete document, no field in that:)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're supposed to execute a PUT request containing the modified document, and the _rev of the version you're modifying.